# Add / Remove class of button when Clicked by user

Tags: css, angular, angular12

I am using Angular 12 and I have a button:

```
<button class="action">Sign In</button>
```

I need to add a CSS Class when it is being clicked by the user so I can change its style.

The moment it stops being clicked the style should be removed.

I tried with CSS but wasn't able. I think it is not possible.

Is it possible to do this with an Angular directive?

Comment: Does `:active` meet your expectations? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

Comment: Yea, just `button.action:active { /*do stuff to style*/}` will do what you appear to be requiring.

Answer (score -1):

Import ElementRef from the angular core and define in constructor then try the below code:

The below line of code will give you the first occurrence of the button tag from the Component. querySelector gives you the first item and querySelectorAll gives you all items from DOM.

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
}

let myTag = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector("button");
```

Add Class:

```
if(!myTag.classList.contains('myClass'))
{
    myTag.classList.add('myClass'); 
}
```

Remove Class:

```
myTag.classList.remove('myClass');
```